# How to stop execution of outer function from a inner function?

Tags: python

Here is what I want to do:

```
def bfunc():
    try:
        do_someting
    except Exception as e:
        return

def afunc():
    bfunc()
    xxx

def cfunc():
    xxx

def main():
    afunc()
    cfunc()
```

in bfunc(),I catch the exception.Now in my main(), I want to stop the afunc() execution when an exception occurs but proceed to execute cfunc().
How can I do this or is there any other way to catch the exception without too many nested try statements?
Tx

Comment: but bfunc is being executed as part of `afunc`.  You can `return` as part of your exception to halt execution of `afunc` at that point, but there is no "going back" if that's what you're looking for (thank god)

Comment: The code you show will naturally do what you want so long as the first `xxx` does not throw an exception.  `bfunc` will return, then so will `afunc` because it doesn't do anything more after calling `bfunc`. Then you'll be back in `main` and will execute `cfunc`.  I think the main thing you're struggling with is what happens when you catch an exception like you do in `bfunc`.  When you do that, execution  transfers to the `except` block (xxx), and  the code just runs line by line from there.  With your current code and what you say you want, there's no need for another try/catch block.

Comment: @anon01Sorry,I did return bfunc, forgot to show it here.

Comment: @CryptoFool Sorry, I need to do something more in afunc, forgot to show it here.My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Because `bfunc()` is a function, therefore, to stop the execution of `bfunc` you can simply use `return` to stop `bfunc`. This won't affect `cfunc` because `return` only affect `bfunc`.

```py
def bfunc():
    try:
        # do_someting
    except Exception as e:
        return # Exit the bfunc() immediately
```

You can use below code to see whether `print` will work or not

```py
def bfunc():
    try:
        raise IndexError
    except Exception as e:
        return

def main():
    bfunc()
    print("Hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you mean to call `bfunc` in `main`, not `dfunc`?  If so, then I'd suggest that you also explain a bit better what you're demonstrating.  I think I know, but the OP might not get it.

Comment: Sorry,I did return bfunc, forgot to show it here.

Comment: Already changed it! Thanks for @CryptoFool checking.

Comment: @peterchen145 Even if you want to do more things in `afunc`, `return` won't break anything except `bfunc`. You just use `return` to ensure that you can immediately break `bfunc` when errors happen.

Comment: @JustinRuan Thx, but I want to break `afunc` when errors happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the try exception block to `afunc`. It should give the effect you want.

```py
def bfunc():
    do_someting
    
def afunc():
    try:
        bfunc()
    except Exception as e:
        return
    xxx #you can move it to try block in order to catch exceptions here too, but I don't know if it's what you like to do
```